# Javascript tabbed data, reveal on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My issue is that I cannot get my tabs to show my data using the javascript that I wrote. It will show on page load(the default action) but will not display any of the tab_content when i use the navigation.

The Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Default Action

  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  $("dl.tabs dd:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
  $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

  //On Click Event
  $("dl.tabs dd").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
      $("dl.tabs dd").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
      $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
      $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
      var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
      $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
      return false;
  });
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="six columns">
  <div class="panel">
    <dl class="nice vertical tabs">
        <dd><a id="(dynamic id)">(tab name)</a><dd>
        <dd><a id="(dynamic id)">(tab name)</a><dd>
        <dd><a id="(dynamic id)">(tab name)</a><dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="six columns">
    <div id="(dynamic id)" class="panel tabs_content">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="(dynamic id)" class="panel tabs_content">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="(dynamic id)" class="panel tabs_content">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically will work once you fix mismatch of class name `tab_content` vs `tabs_content` and include href in your `A` tags. There currently is no href for code to lookup

The href needs to be in format "#idValue"

I made these 2 changes and here is working demo

http://jsfiddle.net/WFW6k/1/

Comment: Accepted I see what I did wrong now, The tabs_content thing was a spelling problem I didn't have in my code :O oops

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery object is empty,  look at it's selector:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
$(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
```

`activeTab` is the `href` attribute, not a selector nor a DOM element, why should it work...?

Comment: if href is "#idValue" it does work with code posted.  OP doesn't have any href's in markup.   Example http://jsfiddle.net/n9D9G/